# Can I put tsconfig file in one project and use it in another?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have submodule in my solution projects. Both of them(1st 2nd projects) have .ts files, so I want to put tsconfig.json in submodule and share it for both of them.

In file system they are located like this:

```
~/solution
--project1
  --Scripts
    --(ts files)
--submodule
  --tsconfig.json(I want to put it here)

~/solution
--project2
  --Scripts
    --(ts files)
--submodule

project1's name is equal with project2's name
```

I have tried to add rootDir to compilerOptions

```
   "rootDir": "..\\project1\\Scripts\\**\\*"
```

I tried to add

```
  "include": [
    "..\\project1\\Scripts\\**\\*"
  ]
```

None of them work for me.

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "none",
    "types": [],
    "emitBOM": false,
    "charset": "utf8"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to share the tsconfig file (as the title suggests), or do you want to share the typescript files (as your attempts suggest)?

Comment: @Arjan I want to share tsconfig file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share a tsconfig between two projects, you can extend a `tsconfig.json` file. For example you have a shared file `shared.json`.
Each project would have it's own `tsconfig.json` file and extending the base file `shared.json`, like so:

```
{
  "extends": "../shared",
  <options here that are different>
}
```

More info on this page:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Thank's @Arjan! It's - what I want!